# Python script does not work but gives no error message

Tags: python

I am new to programming/scripting in general and just becoming to understand the basics of the workings of python2.7. Anyways, i have here a script i have been working on to randomly generate a password made up of letters, numbers and special characters.

```
import random

charset="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
charset+=charset.lower()   # adds lowercase a-z to charset
charset+="@&%_$#" # adds these special characters to the charset
charset+="1234567890" # adds digits 0-9 to charset

def generate_password(length):
  """generates random password"""
    password=[]
    for n in range(length):
        password.append(random.choice(charset))
        print password
    return password

def main():
    # test cases
    length = 4

  # boilerplate 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please excuse if this seems like a stupid question but i am new to this after all :(. When i run the above script i receive no output as well as no error message resulting in me not knowing what the heck im doing wrong!

Comment: Where are you using `generate_password()` ?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `main` declares a name `length` for an integer value `4`. That won't produce any output.

Comment: _" When i run the above script i receive no output as well as no error message resulting in me not knowing what the heck i'm doing wrong!"_ - Python is not just going to raise an error because of a bug in your program. That's what a good debugger is for.

Comment: Also a tip: use `import string` and then `charset = string.printable` instead of trying to do it yourself.

Comment: If you want the exact characters, `string` can still help you out:
`charset = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "@&%_$#"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because, your main() function doesn't do anything. Change it as following :

```
def main():
  # test cases
  length = 4
  #
  print generate_password(length)

  # boilerplate 
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

charset="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
charset+=charset.lower()   # adds lowercase a-z to charset
charset+="@&%_$#" # adds these special characters to the charset
charset+="1234567890" # adds digits 0-9 to charset

def generate_password(length):

    password=[]
    for n in range(length):
        password.append(random.choice(charset))

    print password
    return password

def main():
    length = 4
    generate_password(length)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

first you did not have any indentation (that might have been a copy and paste issue). Then you never called generate_password so it would have never done anything but set length to 4.